# Multiple Callbacks to get google maps distance and duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am struggling to produce an infowindow in google maps that displays a list of nearby locations from a mySQL db and their distance and time from a placemark the user can drag around.

The best I can do is to display the locations but not the info for the time and distance - i can access it and display in an alert, but not on the infowindow.  I think my problem is that i am trying to perform 2 actions (mySQL query to get list and google distance matrix api to get time/distnace) that each require callbacks but don't understand how i can combine all the output together to display the infowindow without the undefined values problem.

```
function get_nearby_plants(location){
var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + location.lat() + '&lng=' +  location.lng();
downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
var xml = parseXml(data);
var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {    // replace 1 with markerNodes.length
    buyername[i] = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("BuyerName");
    // more populating arrays
    calculateDistances(pass_start, pass_dest)    // this function is to get drive distances and times and display them but i dont
    // know how to include them with the data in the array
  } // end for i= loop

var c=0;
var output = '<table border=1><tr><td colspan=3><font size=2>Potential Suppliers</td><td><font size=2>Address</td><td><font size=2>Distance</td></font></tr>';
  //to populate an html table to go in the infowindow
  for (c = 0; c < resultcount; c++){
    output = output + '<tr><td><font size=1>' + buyerid[c] + '</td><td><font size=1>' + buyername[c] + '</td><td><font size=1>' + buyerparent[c]+ '</td><td><font size=1>' +
    buyeraddress[c] + '</td><td><font size=1>' + kms[c] + 'km</td><td><font size=1>' + myStart[c] + '</td><td><font size=1>' + myDest[c] + '</td></font></tr>';
  }

  var contentstring='<div id="content"><div id="siteNotice"></div><div id="bodyContent"><p><b>test'+ display_string +'</b></div></div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: output
  });
infowindow.open(map,marker);  
});
} // end function get_nearby_plants()

function calculateDistances(myStart, myDest) {
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix(
  {
    origins: [myStart],
    destinations: [myDest],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, callback);
  }

  function callback(response, status) {
if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
  alert('Error was: ' + status);
} else {
  var origins = response.originAddresses;          
  var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;          
  var mykms=0;
  var mytime=0;
  var timeoutput='';
  var myoutput='<table border=1>';
  deleteOverlays();
  for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
    var results = response.rows[i].elements;
    for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        mykms=Math.round(results[j].distance.text);
        mytime=Math.round(results[j].duration.text);
        timeoutput += origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j] + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in ' + results[j].duration.text + '<p>';
    }  //for j=0
  } //for i=0 (loops through for each instance of a destination to check time/distance from start
} //end else statement
} // end function


function deleteOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markersArray = [];
}
```

Comment: Calls to the maps API for distances are asynchronous. About the only way you would do this is with an array of promises for each of the calls to get distance and don't create the info window until all promises are resolved. Can use jQuery's `Deferred` promise API  http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 0):

You could also calculate distances without any service.

```
function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
  var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
  var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
  var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180;
  var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180;
  var theta = lon1-lon2;
  var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
  var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
  dist = Math.acos(dist);
  dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344; }
  if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684; }
  return dist;
}
```